# how to check the object type

Tags: list, python-2.7, python-3.x

how can I check the type of all the elements in a list?

For example I have a list:

```
li = ["Hello", 12121, False]
```

How can I make a program that goes through each element in a list and outputs the type of each element

Such as "Hell" is a string

12121 is a integer

False is a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Python's built-in [`isintance`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) method, and also the [`type`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) method.  To find out for the whole list, you could simply iterate through the list and output the resultant of the `type` method.

For example:

```
for item in list:
    print type(item)
```

Or if you are expecting certain types:

```
for item in list:
    if isinstance(item,basestring):
        print "I am a type of string!"
    if isinstance(item,(str,unicode)):
        print "I am a str or unicode!"
    if isinstance(item,int):
        print "I am a type of int!"
    if isinstance(item,(int,float)):
        print "I am an int or a float!"
    if isinstance(item,bool):
        print "I am a boolean!"
    if isinstance(True,bool):
        print "I am a boolean!"
    if isinstance(True,int):
        print "I am an int!"  # because booleans inherit from integers ;)
```

The `isinstance` method is usually better because it checks against inherited classes. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python) for a detailed discussion.

Comment: @user2891763 You can use a tuple for the argument in `isinstance` to compare against multiple types.  I made an edit to demonstrate.